# Is it possible to tell the number of mappers / reducers used based on number of files?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I am wondering if its possible to tell the number of mappers / reducers used (by default) based on the number of files?

I know number of mapper depends on the block size rather than actual file size but want to make sure if I am missing anything there.

For ex:

if there are 4 directories in hdfs with 4 files in them.

```
dir1/file1 - contains (testing file 1, testing again)
dir2/file2 - contains (testing file 2, testing again)
dir3/file3 - contains (testing file 3, testing again)
dir4/file4 - contains (testing file 4, testing again)
```

Is there a way to tell how many mappers and reducers would be used to process the above four files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Number of Mappers depends on the number of splits, however if the files are less then the split size  then each file will correspond to one mapper. that is the reason large number of small files are not recommended

determining properties to decide split size and there default values are as follows

```
  mapred.min.split.size=1 (in bytes)
  mapred.max.split.size=Long.MAX_VALUE
  dfs.block.size=64 MB
```

split size is calculated as

```
   inputSplitSize=max(minimumSize, min(maximumSize, blockSize))

  # of mappers= totalInputSize/inputSplitSize
```

Number of Reducers depends on -D mapred.reduce.tasks=# of reducers argument. The Java API will try to derive the number of reducers you will need but again you can explicitly set that too. In both cases, there is a hard cap on the number of reducers you can run per node and that is set in your mapred-site.xml configuration file using mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum

default values

```
  mapred.reduce.tasks=1
  mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum=2
```

here is a nice reference about number of Mappers and reducers on apache wiki http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces

Comment: So if I dont set any value of the reducer, how many reducers will be invoked for 4 mappers? By default is it 1?

Comment: updated the answer with default values and other relevant info. yes if you have not set that explicitly then it would be 1

Answer (score 1):

The number of mappers depends on the number of files, the hdfs block size property AND the `mapred.min.split.size` property, which determines the minimum size that a split needs to be in order for the file to be actually split.

Let's say you have two input files, each 128Mb,

If the hdfs block size is 128 Mb then you will spawn 2 mappers (independently of the min split size).

If the hdfs block size is actually smaller than the file size (say 32 Mb), then it will depend on your min split size as well. In case it's smaller than the hdfs block size, 4 mappers per file will be spawned, whereas if it's bigger (say 64 Mb), the file will be split according to this value, hence 2 mappers per file will be spawned.

The number of reducers, however, is almost entirely up to you (as you can set the exact number of reducers you'd like through the `setNumReduceTasks` method).